# Can I make a pig follow me with wheat? Or a carrot?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I got wheat and the pig won't follow! I've heard that you can but it won't let me! And I've also heard that you can use a carrot! But how do you get a carrot in Minecraft pocket edition?

Comment: I think this may have changed in the most recent version

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, on Pocket Edition, you'll have to use potatoes or beetroots.  https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding#Mechanics

http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/e/e4/Beetbreeding.jpg


If that doesn't work, you can always try pushing them...  :)

Answer (score 0):

You do need a carrot to make a pig follow you from one place to another. For more information on how to obtain carrots, visit my earlier question at this link. Visit [Finding carrot seeds in Minecraft PE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172043/finding-carrot-seeds-in-minecraft-pe)