# Finding carrot seeds in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have done some research and know that you can breed pigs with carrots. How do you get carrot seeds to plant carrots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep on killing zombies, until you get one from them. Then, plant the carrot in hoed/tiled ground (grass) and wait until it shows orange at the bottom. Finally, harvest it and it should drop 1-3 carrots. Once finished, just repeat steps 2-3 for more carrots

Comment: Useful answer... +1

Answer (score 8):

The carrots themselves are the seeds. You can just plant the carrots you have, then they will grow and "duplicate".

[Source and more information](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Carrot)

Comment: Same goes for potatoes, by the way.

Comment: Pat answer... -1

Answer (score 6):

Unlike Wheat, planting carrots requires that you have carrots already, which is kind of a catch-22 if you have none to start with.

Carrots were added to PE in [0.8.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history#A0.8.0) (December 2013) as a rare drop from Zombies.

Once you have a single carrot, planting it and then harvesting it when fully grown will drop 1-4 carrots, so from that point onward you're likely to get them faster from farming.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get carrots, you must kill a zombie. After you have killed the zombie, you simply till the ground and plant the carrot in the tilled ground.

Comment: I will add a picture if I have some time.